# NGINX server-name and root for a webserver on a local network without any DNS and without configuring etc/hosts on the client

Tags: nginx

I am completely new to Nginx and php. I have a Baikal self-hosted webserver on my local network and I do not use a DNS. I would like to use it for synchronizing contacts and calendars with my PC and my Android phone.
I have read Nginx tutorial and googled a lot but I still cannot figure out what to use as server-name in nginx and what to use as URL for the client.
I tried :
server_name baikal in Nginx and http://baikal as URL. This works if etc/hosts on the client PC includes baikal. It fails otherwise.
without configuring etc/hosts on the client I tried :
server_name baikal 192.168.1.27/baikal URl
in the client : http://192.168.1.27/baikal produces a 404 error and in the access log Nginx looks for /baikal
What should I use as server name and as url?

Answer (score 0):

On server side
/etc/nginx/sites-available/baikal file must listen on ip address

```
server {
listen 192.168.1.27:80;
server_name baikal;
root /var/www/baikal;,....
```

On client side
just type on your browser the ip address 192.168.1.27  and it works